# If I held fiat currency, instead BTC, on MT Gox, would I get paid sooner/more?

Tags: mtgox

If I held currency on Mt. Gox, but not actually bitcoins, am I in a different situation to those who held bitcoins? For example, if I had $700 AUD but 0 BTC. I can't get any information regarding this online and do not think contacting Mt. Gox would be helpful (nor possible).

Related, but concerned about BTC held in Mt. Gox rather than fiat: [I have/had 31 bitcoins on MtGox; What are my options now?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22641/i-have-had-31-bitcoins-on-mtgox-what-are-my-options-now)

Thanks

Comment: Mt. Gox have been liquidated. Your situation is no different from everyone else, unfortunately. You wont get your money sooner, if at all, than everyone else. It's sad to realize, but you cant do much.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, that is what I thought. 

Cheers for the info!

Comment: I've found more information if you are keen to try and get your money back, everything I've said is now in an answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are in the same boat as all the people that had BTC at Mt.Gox. Think about it positively, you are now part of a club of people that all had their money stolen / lost.

If you are keen to try and get your money back, keep checking in at http://www.reddit.com/r/mtgoxinsolvency. But if you are taking this route, prepare to be really patient.

Here is the latest update from the above reddit thread.

> LAST UPDATE: 3 JANUARY 2015 11:00 AM GMT
>
> NOTE: Progress is slow nowadays, so this current state of affairs sticky thread should be up to date.
>
> A note on recovering funds: From announcement dated 26 November 2014:
>
> The deadline for filing the proof of claims of bankruptcy in these bankruptcy proceedings is set as May 29, 2015, and we plan to disclose the necessary information one or two months prior to the said deadline. The bankruptcy trustee will make effort to ensure that creditors around the world have a reasonable period of time in which to file proofs of claim.
>
> Important dates: From announcement dated July 24th 2014:
>
> Period for filing proofs of bankruptcy claims: By May 29, 2015
>
> Date and time for investigation of claims: September 9, 2015, 1:30 pm.